# Need to change previous value

Tags: sas

Lets say we have the following  data set

```
obs    check   result
---------------------
aa     0       0
bb     0       0
cc     1       0
dd     0       0
ee     1       1 
ff     1       1 <- we are here. Due to prev. value both eq 1 the "result" variable for both of them should also be 1
```

What I need is to check if 2 or more cases in "check" variable in a row are equal to 1 and if so, "result" variable for both of them should also be 1. The problem is that the only way I see to set "result" to 1 for both of them is to somehow go back to the previous "observed row" and change "result" variable there to 1 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way the Data step loop is designed, I don't think we can go back to a previous observation that easily. However, we can use a `retain` statement and `merge`ing the data set with itself `without` a `by` statement to access previous or next observations:

```
data work.sample;
    input obs $ check result;
    retain x;
    output;
    x = check;
    datalines;
    aa     0       0 
    bb     0       0
    cc     1       0
    dd     0       0
    ee     1       0 
    ff     1       0
    ;
run;

data work.sample2;
    merge work.sample
    work.sample(firstobs = 2 keep = check 
    rename = (check = c));
    if (check = 1 and x = 1) or (check = 1 and c = 1) then result = 1; 
run;
```

OUTPUT would look like this:

```
                      Obs    obs    check    result    x    c

                       1     aa       0         0      .    0
                       2     bb       0         0      0    1
                       3     cc       1         0      0    0
                       4     dd       0         0      1    1
                       5     ee       1         1      0    1
                       6     ff       1         1      1    .
```

So, variable x represents the values that are retained using the `retain` statement and `output` statement. variable c represents the variable that we created when we merged the data set with itself beginning when observation = 2.

Lastly, we follow this up with a conditional statement to put the new values into result variable if there exists a consecutive occurrence of check = 1.

Answer (score 2):

Yick's answer is a very good general approach, but this specific problem has an interesting, simpler answer.

There is one way in SAS of looking ahead without having to read the data a second time in some fashion: The `LAST.<variable>` automatic variables created by using a `BY` statement.  These involve an automatic lookahead that SAS does without forcing you to do it by hand.  Thanks to `NOTSORTED`, this lets you see if the next value is precisely equal to the current value for a variable.

Using Yick's dataset:

```
data work.sample;
    input obs $ check result;
    retain x;
    output;
    x = check;
    datalines;
    aa     0       0 
    bb     0       0
    cc     1       0
    dd     0       0
    ee     1       0 
    ff     1       0
    ;
run;

data want;
set sample;
by check notsorted;
if not (first.check and last.check) and (check=1) then result=1;  
*if it is not the first record AND the last record with the same check value in a row,
 then it is one of a sequence of two or more and if check=1 then result should be 1;
put _all_;
run;
```